# Rate of convergence for Beta posterior

Tags: self-study, bayesian, convergence

Recently I started studying posterior distribution rates of convergence.

In order to check what I understand I tried to formulate an example. Let $X_{1}, X_{2},..., X_{n}\sim Bin(N,p)$, we then assinge a prior to parameter $p\sim Beta(a,b)$ and due to conjugancy we derive the posterior $p|X_{1}, X_{2},..., X_{n} \sim Beta(a+\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i},b+nN-\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i})$

If $p_{0}$ is the true value of the parameter $p$ I would like to calculate the rate of convergence to that true value.

I think in order to calculate that rate I have to check how fast the following probability converges to zero.

$$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}Pr(\left | p-p_{0} \right |\geq \epsilon|X_{1}, X_{2},...,X_{n})=0$$

In order to calculate that, I believe I could use the same arguments as displayed here [Proof of posterior consistency](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320104/proof-of-posterior-consistency), however, I do not understand how they went from triangular inequality to the probabilities inequality, especially how they used the property of monotonicity.

Thus, I would like to ask

$1)$ How did they derive the result in [Proof of posterior consistency](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320104/proof-of-posterior-consistency), in order to continue by myself.

$2)$ If there is a formal definition of rate of posterior convergence, because at the moment I've found a dozen of them.

Comment: You can't emulate the posterior consistency proof because it only shows convergence occurs.  Chebyshev's Inequality does not yield information about the rate of convergence.  One approach is to appeal to the Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: @whuber Then how do we calculate the rate of convergence for posterior distributions?? A definition that I found is: "Let $\epsilon_{n}>0$ a decreasing to zero sequences, and suppose that for any constant $M_{n}\rightarrow \infty$, $$Pr(d(p,p_{0})\geq M_{n}\epsilon_{n}|X_{1}, X_{2},...,X_{n}))\rightarrow 0$$  then $\epsilon_{n}$ corresponds to the rate of convergence.

Comment: I can't make any sense of what "constant $M_n\to\infty$" is intended to mean, because it seems to be a contradiction in terms ("constant" values don't diverge!)  Ordinarily, you would adopt a definition of rate of convergence that is suitable for whatever analysis you are performing: there isn't necessarily one universal meaning.

Comment: That's true is quite weird, the paper that gives this definition is "Misspesification in Infinite Dimensional"